# Alinear texto en CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, canvas

Estoy utilizando CanvasJS y necesito alinear esas etiquetas a la izquierda, ademas me gustaria agregarles una imagen como por ejemplo la bandera del pais.

CDN de la libreria: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js

```
    chart_dist_per = new CanvasJS.Chart("dist_per_grafico", {
    exportEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Distribuidores Con Más Personalizaciones - "+meses[parseInt(mes)]+' '+year,
        fontFamily: "Open sans, sans-serif, arial",
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "",
        labelFontSize: 0
    },
    axisX: {
        labelFontFamily: "Open sans, sans-serif, arial",
        labelFontSize: 13,
        labelMaxWidth: 200,
        labelWrap: false
    },
    legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick : toggleDataSeries
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true,
        content: toolTipFormatter_dist_per,
        fontFamily: "Open sans, sans-serif, arial",
    },
    data: [{
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "",
        color: "#0065A4",
        indexLabelTextAlign: "left",
        dataPoints: array_dist_per     
    },
    ]
});
```

He probado agregar al axisX labelTextAlign: "left" y no funciona.

He probado agregar al dataPoints indexLabelTextAlign: "left" y tampoco funciona.

Ya he revisado la documentacion de CanvasJS y nada.

Les agradezco la ayuda que puedan darme con esos 2 requerimientos.

[image: Grafico CanvasJS]

Comment: Considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar: 1. el código que crea el gráfico. 2. la libreria que utilizas. 3. los datos para replicar el gráfico. Gracias!

Comment: Solo cuando los textos ocupa más de una línea, estos se alinean según lo indicado en `labelTextAlign` del `axis`. Con respecto a agregar una imagén, por lo que pude ver, no soporta HTML.